# Add a parameter to an MDX-Query

Tags: visual-studio, parameters, report, mdx

I am building a Report in MS Visual Studio which gets its data from a cube. This has amongst others a dimension called Player. I want to hand over a parameter 'Name' and receive the number of games the player has played. But I do not get the parameter integrated in the MDX-query I use. I had defined the parameter and in the query, I tried
many different things, e.g.

```
Select 
strtomember('@Name')
on 1,
[Measures].[Match Count]
on 0
From [Kicker Manager Data Warehouse]
```

and instead of `strtomember('@Name')` for ex.

```
[Dimension Player].[@Name]
```

but nothing works. Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is `strtomember(@Name)`.

In the query designer, I had to define the parameter once again
(dialogue "Query Parameters").

Answer (score 0):

MDX does not support parameters like SQL stored procedures do.

You could look at using the SQL command `OPENROWSET` which allows a SQL proc to execute some MDX and return the results in a normal (2D) recordset. The MDX would then be a string that you could format how you like in the calling code or in the proc.

Or look at executing MDX using ADOMD from Visual Studio (or am I a bit out of date there?). Again, you'd pass it a string.

Comment: This is incorrect, however the ADO.Net providers for SSAS don't correctly implement the parameterisation. You can parameterize an MDX query if you use the ADO COM interfaces (which is what SSRS does), but if you are calling from .Net you have to parameterise the query yourself.